# case object of generic trait

Tags: scala, traits

In Scala: I would like to define a type Message[T] (it needs to have this signature), which can be a message holding some data of type T, or an implicit message. I have

```
trait Message[T]
case object ImplicitMessage extends Message <- obviously doesn't compile
case class DataMessage[T](d: T) extends Message[T]
```

How should I define ImplicitMessage? I could make it a case class, but that is obviously not that nice, as it only want one instance of it.

UPDATE: I know I could simply remove [T] from Message, but I can't (requirement).

Answer (score 4):

You could use `Nothing` as in:

```
case object ImplicitMessage extends Message[Nothing]
```

`Nothing` is a special type which is a subtype of all possible types and has no instances.

If you experience variance problems because of `Message[T]` you can use the following trick:

```
object ImplicitMessage extends Message[Nothing] {
  def apply[T]: Message[T] = this.asInstanceOf[Message[T]]
}

scala> ImplicitMessage[String]
res1: Message[String] = ImplicitMessage$@4ddf95b5
scala> ImplicitMessage[Long]
res2: Message[Long] = ImplicitMessage$@4ddf95b5
```

Comment: I'm getting an error when trying to use ImplicitMessage where a Message[T] is expected: type mismatch Note: Nothing <: T (and Test.ImplicitMessage.type <: Test.Message[Nothing]), but trait Message is invariant in type T.

Comment: make in covariant: `trait Message[+T]`

Comment: I can't, I _have_ to use this signature: Message[T]. Is there any other way to do it...?

Comment: @user1377000 Here comes a nice trick which avoids to instantiate more than one object.

Comment: @paradigmatic in this case creating ImplicitMessage is useless, see my edit

Comment: @AloisCochard Using an object you can still add methods and you can still be able to pattern match it (if you add the correct unapply method).

Comment: @paradigmatic there is no unapply in your example, and I don't see any need for pattern matching in the original question. It should be added that for your example to be useful in a real context, the `apply` method have to be implicit and the caller need to import `ImplicitMessage._` at the end of the day, I don't see the point of creating that object.

Comment: @AloisCochard the example just works in the REPL, no implicits needed. But I agree, if there are no methods in trait `Message` and if pattern matching is not needed, your solution is the best.

Comment: `Nothing` does not _inherit from_ all types. It is a _subtype of_ all types. (There's also `Null` which is a subtype of all `AnyRef` subtypes.)

Comment: @RandallSchulz Thanks for the precision, I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can by defining an implicit method with a type parameter like this:

```
implicit def message[T]: Message[T] = new Message[T] {}
```

**EDIT:** If you really one only one instance (which you really shouldn't do because your are lying to the compiler and this is highly probably that you are doing it wrong), you can simply cast null:

```
implicit def message[T]: Message[T] = null.asInstancOf[Message[T]]
```

Comment: In that case there would be more than one instance.